# Toast not showing in espresso test

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso, instrumentation, android-instrumentation

I wanted to test a Toast message using Espresso, but when I am calling the method to show toast, the toast is not showing.
It shows when I run the app normally, but when I run the test, no toast shows up.

```
fun Context.showMessage(@StringRes message:Int){
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

I am calling `showMessage()` in the TestFragment's showMessage method which is called in FragmentScenario's `onFragment`

```
override fun showMessage(message: Int) {
    context?.showMessage(message)
}
```

```
val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<TestFragment>()
scenario.onFragment {
     it.showMessage(R.string.test_string)
     onView(withText(it.context.getString(R.string.test_string))
          .inRoot(ToastMatcher())
          .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
}
```

The test case is just stuck at

```
check(matches(isDisplayed()))
```

and I guess its because there is no toast displayed.

Comment: I'm having this issue right now. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Move the espresso assertion outside of `onFragment()`.

```
scenario.onFragment { it.showMessage(R.string.test_string) }
onView(withText(R.string.test_string))
     .inRoot(ToastMatcher())
     .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
```

ps: `withText()` accepts `String` resources ids.

Comment: Nope. That's not working. Actually I think the main problem is that it's not showing any toast message. thanks anyway.